# Android retrofit GET request with 5 Different params as parcel array

Tags: android, interface, retrofit, parcel

I want to send parcel array as params for retrofit GET request.

For example:

Params list as android parcel array

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(userId);
    dest.writeInt(page);
    dest.writeInt(pageSize);
    dest.writeStringList(name);
    dest.writeStringList(places);
}
```

Retrofit GET request in java interface

```
public interface Interfacename {
    @GET("/_ah/api/path/v2/apiname/")
    Observable<ResponceName> Methodname(@Header(QPARAM_HEADERTOKEN) String accessToken, @QueryMap ParcelClassName ParcelObject);
}
```

The problem here is params in interface, I have tried @QueryMap, But, It's not working. Retrofit offers one by one params in GET request. similar to this

```
@GET("/weather")
void getWheatherReport(@Query("q") String place, @Query("appid") String appId, Callback<Model> cb);
```

I need send parcel array as params. Similar to body request with parcel array. shown below.

```
public interface Interfacename {
    @POST("/_ah/api/path/v2/apiname/")
    Observable<ResponceName> Methodname(@Header(QPARAM_HEADERTOKEN) String accessToken, @Body ParcelClassName ParcelObject);
}
```

The above post with body parcel array is working fine. I want similar request for GET Medthod

Comment: do you want to send an array of items of the same type as parameters?

Comment: Yeah!. But, Not as Hashmap. I just want to send as android parcel array. Similar like POST method body params.

Comment: You'll have to serialize the array to String and pass that string as @Query parameter. But if I were you, I'd use POST method.

Comment: @Євген Гарастович. Have you tried serialize the array to string method?

Comment: no, I haven't. I use POST for your scenario. it's a much better approach.